# Winform - Show mainform, wait, then modify label

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been trying to perform the simple task written in the title. I could only think of using timer, thread sleep or background worker, but I'm going to do this task only once.. so I would like to avoid making a lot of functions or such just for one time. I tried thread sleep but it doesn't show the mainform before the sleep... Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `System.Threading.Timer` in the `Form.Load` event:

```
private const int DelayMilliseconds = 500;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new System.Threading.Timer(_ => Invoke(new Action(() => _myLabel.Text = "bla")),
                               null,
                               DelayMilliseconds,
                               Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Since you only specify a delay and no period, the timer will run exactly once. However, since the timer callback is executed on a different thread, you need to `Invoke` the action that modifies the label on the UI thread.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest option is to use `await Task.Delay`:

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(timespan);
    label1.Text = "Hello world";
}
```

If you don't have access to `await` using the version of .NET that you're using, then your best bet would be to use a `Timer`.  Yes it's a fair bit of code.  That's simply reflecting the complexity of asynchronous operations.  `await` does a lot to make this simpler; without it, it's just not a problem that lends itself to terse solutions.

Comment: one example by using timer please

Comment: +1. That's pretty nice and certainly better than my answer if .NET 4.5 is available.

Comment: I couldn't use this solution probably because of my .NET. I have framework 4. Too bad can't mark more answers

Answer (score 0):

Use a System.Timer instance

- make an eventhandler with Timer.Elapsed
- set timer interval
- start timer as application fires up
  -after the timer elapses set your label
  -stop timer